# html move text up animate from initial position

Tags: javascript, css, animation, text

I am trying to see how I can have text float upward from the initial position in a slideshow. Like how [OnGuardian](http://www.onguardian.io) does on their site. I have tried CSS animated and w3 animate but the problem is it does not move up from the set position it just moves from bottom to up to original position. I am open to using CSS, Javascript, & HTML.

Here is my code

```
    <li style="background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 100%), url(Images/homepage1.jpg)">
       <img  class ="slider-image" src="Images/tenniscentrallogo1.png">
        <!-- <div class="slider-logo "><span></span></div> -->
        <div class="slider-content ">
          <div class="slider-container ">
            <div class="slider-center ">
              <div class=" w3-animate-bottom slider-header">
                <h2> Financial freedom & fun at your fingertips </h2>
              </div>
              <p class = " w3-animate-bottom slidertext"> Take an  quantum leap into the future. Start a lucrative tennis business today with our dynamic team at your service</p>
                <a class="btn play-video-btn" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" preload="auto">Watch the video</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
```

I want to animated the slider-header class and the slider-text class. My issues is more related to not being able to know how to find the desired effect.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you show us your code?

Comment: Post the code you use if you want to get a proper answer

Comment: Hey @KobyDouek. I have tried using https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_animate.asp/ but that only moves text up to down or down to up. What I want is to go up a bit and stop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can definitely do this with pure CSS, as long as it's a simple animation. I've created a demo for

```
@keyframes floatup {
  from {transform: translateY(0px);}
  to {transform: translateY(-100px);}
}
```

That will start the object where it's already styled / located, then move it. To use the keyframes, add the following statement to your code:

```
animation: floatup 2s forwards;
```

Call 'floatup' or your keyframes name to animate the object; set the duration with 2s.

**Most importantly: Use `forwards` to tell the object to stay in the new location** (20px higher in the above keyframe) after animating.

I've demo'd this with your HTML, on Codepen.
https://codepen.io/laureng/pen/LyzBbz

(Note: I added a few "reset" styles so you could see it without the default body padding / ul padding / etc., and added a random Google image since we don't have access to your site's /images/ folder.)

Comment: Since the code is unknown, any answer will be a guess, and we don't guess here at SO

Comment: @Roshan, I have tweaked my answer based on your code, and provided a codepen to see it in action. Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: @LaurenG thank you so much!!! your solution worked. It's people like you that make this community great. Thank you for explaining the solution to me and providing helpful steps on Codepen. I understand the power of Keyframes now!

Comment: @Roshan - Happy to help :) I'm glad the solution worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your text has `position:absolute;` in the style declaration then try using CSS3 animation of the `bottom` property.

```
    @-webkit-keyframes moveUp {
          from { bottom : /* initial */ ; }
          to { bottom : /* some extent of move up like initial - 30px */ ; }
    }


    #text {
      -webkit-animation-name : moveUp ;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards ; /* to avoid the element going back to the initial position */
    }
```

Comment: Since the code is unknown, any answer will be a guess, and we don't guess here at SO

Comment: LGSon , you are one of the million reasons I hate this community.This site is full of hate and everybody is searching for the other's mistakes.To point out your own mistake, in an abbreviation like yours you have to add a dot after each abbreviated word.What you wrote is an incomplete chemistry formulla.And because even error messages should come with suggestion, here are some: SO_2 , SO^-. I really don't care if I get banned or warned 'cause this cummunity will never be better.

Comment: First , if you didn't understood what I meant, you could have done what most people do, asked for a clarification. Second, since English is not my mother tongue, I most likely make a lot of such mistakes. Third, and last, out of curiosity, since you hate this community so much, may I then ask why do you stay here for 5 months?

Comment: LGSon To answer people like you their stupid questions.English is not my mother tongue too.

Comment: Thank your for answering, that comment says it all.

Comment: Good that you are clever! I hated on your comment because it is clear that the person who posted the question is a new person on this site and seriously, there isn't other online community in the whole world which respects the rules so promptly.Even though he didn't post the code at first, he needed help as any other on this community.Hate brings hate.Help and understanding brings more help and understanding and this is how the world should be.

Comment: Thank you @AlfiLouis for your support of me. I came looking for help and what I found was hatred from LGSon. I understand the rules better now and will be a more productive member